# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on a issue with Single Table Inheritance. I have two different types of Users. User model and Trainer model, Trainer user should inherit attributes from the User model. I created a User in the rails console and everything worked. As soon as I attempted to create a Trainer I get the following error.
Rails 5.0.4

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist
```

Am I setting up my model associations incorrectly?

Here is my User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My Trainer Model

```
class Trainer < User

  has_many :appointments
  has_many :clients, through: :appointments
end
```

Schema for models

```
create_table "trainers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "type"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

As you can see from my User model, I added the required :type column

Here is the schema for my client and appointment

```
create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.integer  "trainer_id"
    t.datetime "appointment_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.integer  "status",           default: 0
  end

  create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
```

First I created a user in the console

```
User.create!(email:'ryan@test.com', password:'asdfasdf', password_confirmation:'asdfasdf')
```

Then I when on to create a Trainer

```
Trainer.create!(first_name:'Ryan', last_name:'Bent')
```

Trainers and Users should be associated. But I didn't think I needed add associations using Single Table Inheritance.

Comment: Are `trainers` and `users` associated? Is there any association between them? Also provide structure of `appointments` and `clients`.

Comment: Please provide more code (clients and appointment schema) and what you try to run in console.

Comment: Hopefully by "encrypted_password" you don't actually mean encrypted but rather a password hash such as `PBKDF2` or `BCrypt`.

Comment: @zaph that's just what the Devise library calls that column and yes it uses `BCrypt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Single Table Inheritance, one table must have all the attributes that any of the subclasses need ([more information](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)). So for your situation, you'd need to add the Trainer columns (first_name, last_name) to the `users` table as well, and then Users would leave that empty on the table and Trainers would fill them in.

If you want to keep the separate tables, what you are doing is no longer *single table* and would require some sort of joining between the 2.